# All possible distinct subsets of characters in a given string JAVA

Tags: java, string, function, recursion, subset

As title says I need to do the following. But I somehow am getting the wrong answer, perhaps something with the loops is wrong?

And here's what I have coded so far, but it seems to be giving me the wrong results. Any ideas, help, tips, fixes?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class pro1
{
private String lettersLeft;
private ArrayList<String> subsets;

public pro1(String input)
{
    lettersLeft = input;
    subsets = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void createSubsets()
{       
    if(lettersLeft.length() == 1)
    {
        subsets.add(lettersLeft);
    }
    else
    {
        String removed = lettersLeft.substring(0,1);
        lettersLeft = lettersLeft.substring(1);
        createSubsets();
        for (int i = 0; i <= lettersLeft.length(); i++)
        {
            String temp = removed + subsets.get(i);
            subsets.add(temp);
        }
        subsets.add(removed);
    }
}

public void showSubsets()
{
    System.out.print(subsets);
}
}
```

My test class is here:

```
public class pro1
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    pro1s = new pro1("abba");
    s.createSubsets();
    s.showSubsets();
}
}
```

Comment: I think its simpler to use another approach - if length of string X, generate all numbers between 1 and 2**X - 1. If in binary representation bit set to one - use it index as element of existing subset.

Comment: Surely there are 9, not 11, you've only listed 10 and aba is not a substring of abba?

Comment: @Adam you are right about the count being wrong (it should be 10), but note that he asked for subsets not substrings.  From his desired output, it is evident that he wants unique ordered subsets of the ordered set of characters in the string.

Comment: @Matthew Yes sorry, I misread the question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int numSubsets = (int)java.lang.Math.pow(2,toSubset.length());
for (int i=1;i<numSubsets;i++) {
    String subset = "";
    for (int j=0;j<toSubset.length();j++) {
        if ((i&(1<<j))>0) {
            subset = subset+toSubset.substring(j,j+1);
        }
    }
    if (!subsets.contains(subset)) {
        subsets.add(subset);
    }
}
```

where `toSubset` is the string that you wish to subset (`String toSubset="abba"` in your example) and `subsets` is the ArrayList to contain the results.

To do this we actually iterate over the power set (the set of all subsets), which has size 2^A where A is the size of the original set (in this case the length of your string).

Each subset can be uniquely identified with a number from 0 to 2^A-1 where the value of the jth bit (0 indexed) indicates if that element is present or not with a 1 indicating presence and 0 indicating absence.  Note that the number 0 represents the binary string 00...0 which corresponds to the empty set.  Thus we start counting at 1 (your example did not show the empty set as a desired subset).

For each value we build a subset string by looking at each bit position and determining if it is a 1 or 0 using bitwise arithmetic.  `1<<j` is the integer with a 1 in the jth binary place and `i&(i<<j)` is the integer with 1's only in the places both integers have a 1 (thus is either 0 or 1 based on if i has a 1 in the jth binary digit).  If i has a 1 in the jth binary digit, we append the jth element of the string.

Finally, as you asked for unique subsets, we check if we have already used that subset, if not, we add it to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get your head all turned around when working with recursion.   Generally, I suspect your problem is that one of the strings you are storing on the way down the recursion rabbit hole for use on the way back up is a class member variable and that your recursive method is a method of that same class.  Try making  lettersLeft a local variable in the `createSubsets()` method.  Something like:

```
public class Problem1
{
private String originalInput;
private ArrayList<String> subsets;

public Problem1(String input)
{
    originalInput = input;
    subsets = new ArrayList<String>();
}

// This is overloading, not recursion.
public void createSubsets()
{    
    createSubsets(originalInput);
}
public void createSubsets(String in)
{       
    if(in.length() == 1)
    {
        // this is the stopping condition, the bottom of the rabbit hole
        subsets.add(in);
    }
    else
    {
        String removed = in.substring(0,1);
        String lettersLeft = in.substring(1);

        // this is the recursive call, and you know the input is getting
        // smaller and smaller heading toward the stopping condition
        createSubsets(lettersLeft);

        // this is the "actual work" which doesn't get performed
        // until after the above recursive call returns
        for (int i = 0; i <= lettersLeft.length(); i++)
        {
            // possible "index out of bounds" here if subsets is 
            // smaller than lettersLeft
            String temp = removed + subsets.get(i);
            subsets.add(temp);
        }
        subsets.add(removed);
    }
}
```

Something to remember when you are walking through your code trying to think through how it will run... You have structured your recursive method such that the execution pointer goes all the way down the recursion rabbit hole before doing any "real work", just pulling letters off of the input and pushing them onto the stack.  All the "real work" is being done coming back out of the rabbit hole while letters are popping off of the stack.  Therefore, the first 'a' in your subsets list is actually the last 'a' in your input string 'abba'. I.E. The first letter that is added to your subsets list is because `lettersLeft.length() == 1`. (`in.length() == 1` in my example).  Also, the debugger is your friend. Step-debugging is a great way to validate that your code is actually doing what you expect it to be doing at every step along the way.